# Send email with attachments with wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and I'm very struggling about this sending an email with attachments :( I don't know what seems to be wrong but I know that I lack some codes.
Please help me. Thank you very much in advanced! :))

Here is my code which is located on two different files.
In my index.php

```
Name (required)<br>         
    <input type="text" class="name"></input>
        Email (required)</br>
        <input type="text" class="e-mail"></input>
        Attach Your Resume</br>
        <input type="file" class="attachment" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png, application/pdf, application/msword"/>
        <div id ="submit"><input id="button-submit" type="submit"></input></div>
        </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-submit').click(function(){
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
    var names = $('.name').val();
    var emails = $('.e-mail').val();
    var attachments = $('.attachment').val();
    if ( names =="" || emails=="" || attachments == ""){
        alert('You must fill all the required fields!');
    }else{
        var pattern=/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/;
        if(pattern.test(emails)){
            /*$('#submit').html('<div class="loader"></div>');*/
            jQuery.ajax({
              url: ajaxurl,
              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'html',
              data: {action: 'resume',
                    txtname: $('.name').val(),
                    txtemail: $('.e-mail').val(),
                    attachment: $('.attachment').val(),
                    },

              complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {

              },
              success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                $('#submit').html('Thank you for submitting!');
                // $('.name').val("");
                // $('.e-mail').val("");
                // $('.attachment').val("");
              },
              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              }
            }); 
        }
        else{
            alert("Invalid E-mail address format.");
        }

    }   
    return false;
});
```

This one is located and declared on my functions.php

```
function resume() {
$name = $_POST['txtname'];
$email = $_POST['txtemail'];
$attachments = $_POST['attachment'];
$headers = 'From: automailer@sample.ph' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: automailer@sample.ph' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$message .= "Contact Details:\n\nName: ".$name."\nEmail: ".$email."\nResume: ";     
        if (file_exists($attachments)) {
            $handle = fopen($attachments, 'r');

            $content = fread($handle, filesize($attachments));

            fclose($handle);
            $message .= '--' . "\n";
            $message .= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="' . basename($attachments) . '"' . "\n";
            $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\n";
            $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($attachments) . '"' . "\n";
            $message .= 'Content-ID: <' . basename(urlencode($attachments)) . '>' . "\n";
            $message .= 'X-Attachment-Id: ' . basename(urlencode($attachments)) . "\n" ."\n";
            $message .= chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        }
        else
        {
            $message .= "Attachment failed to upload.";
        }
mail("sample@outlook.com", 'Careers', $message,$headers);
die();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload files with javascript you need to set the header of your request to accept files:

```
"Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"
```

To implement it into your jQuery script you could also use the FormData class.
Remeber to set these to options in your jQuery ajax request. Otherwise your request will not include the file. See link for more info.

```
contentType: false,
processData: false,
```

See example here : [Sending multipart/formdata with jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Thanks Bjarke, I'll check the link you gave. ! :)

Comment: Is it fine to not to use the '$_FILES[]' to catch the content of my attachment variable and still use '$_POST[]'?

Comment: am I doing it right adding this to my function? $header .= 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;' ."\n";

Comment: In your javascript, you should set the two options (contentType and processData) from the given example and in your PHP file you can grap your file with $_FILES. That should be it :)

Answer (score 0):

> Copy FPDF on your wp-content/theme/yourtheme/  download folder from
>   http://www.fpdf.org/ 
>   Send email with attachments In wordpress

```
    require('../fpdf181/fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12); 
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$buyer_name);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$product_name_semail);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$order_price_semail);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$species_name_semail);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$finish_name_semail);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,$order_date_semail);
    $filename="file-path/order-".$order_id.".pdf";
    $opt=$pdf->Output($filename,'F');
    $to   = $to_mail;
    $from = $from_mail;
    $headers = "From: " . strip_tags($from) . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "CC: v.tamrakar@laxyosolutionsoft.com\r\n";
    $headers.= "BCC: $from\r\n";
    $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $message = '<html><body>';
    $message .= '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:1px solid #3A5896; padding-left:20px">';
    $message .= '<span style="font-size: 14px;margin-bottom: 5px;padding: 7px 10px; background:#999999; color:#ffffff; float:left; margin-right:5px;">Order Confirmation </span>';
    $message .= "<tr><td><h1>Dear $buyer_data->user_login,</h1><br /><br /><tr><td>We Are Heartly Thanks To You. You can Choose Me For Your Order.<br>Your Order Details Here</td></tr>";
    $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:14px;'>Product Details<br /><br /></td><tr><td style='width:20%'>Product Name: Shirt</td></tr>";
    $message.='<tr><td style="width:20%">Category: 'Cloth'</td></td>';
    $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Price: 300/-</td>";
    $message.="<tr><td style='width:20%'>Shipping Date: 25/06/2016</td>";
    $attachments = array(  WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/file_name.pdf' );    
    $message .= "<tr><td style='font-size:12px'><br><I>Thanks & Regards<br>Vivek Tamrakar</I></td><br><br></tr>"; 
    $message .= "</table>";
    $message .= "</body></html>";
    wp_mail( $to, 'Order Confirmation ', $message, $headers,$attachments);
```